# Who is that character in Transformers: Age of Extinction?

Tags: character, transformers, age-of-extinction

In *Transformers: Age of Extinction*, at some point, the main character joins Optimus to help him fight Lockdown.

After some fighting, Lockdown shoots at the main character. However, during a very short moment, there is not one, but two persons being shot at, as shows this screenshot (timestamp: 2.31.09):

[image]

The guy on the left is the main character, but who is the guy on the right ? He was not here a second before and is not here the next second.